# Larevel 8 - Extend a method protected $connection = 'mysql' to a Vendor Model

Tags: laravel-8, voyager

im a newbie developer and want to ask is there any way to add a method to a vendor model, without change the vendor itself ? im just trying to add a

```
protected $connection = 'mysql';
```

to Role.php model on Voyager.

Im using Laravel 8.
I already search that it can use the ServiceProvider thing, but im not quite understand it.

Please your help, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the database connection in .env file